# unable to get a stable set of rows error

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to perform a merge into a table (let's call it `table1`) from a `table2`. In the USING condition I need a third table (`table3`). This third table contains some IDs that I need in `table1`. A simplified version of my merge looks like:

```
MERGE INTO table1 a
                    USING (
                        SELECT ID, address
                        FROM table3 b
                            Where address IN
                            (
                                SELECT address
                                FROM table3 
                                WHERE address IS NOT NULL
                                    AND ID> 0
                                GROUP BY address
                                HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
                            )
                    ) c 
                    ON (a.address = c.address)
                    WHEN MATCHED THEN
                        UPDATE SET a.ID = c.ID
                        WHERE a.ID = 0
```

I know that the error I get is usually caused by the query in the USING clause, but theoretically this problem should be eliminated by the count(*)=1 condition. 
I have duplicates in `table2`, but they should all get an ID from `table3` or ID 0 if the address is duplicated in `table3`. 
IDs are unique for an address, so they should be distinct.

P.S. This merge is performed automatically by a script that , so I can modify the query to add more conditions/restrictions, but I cannot change the structure [meaning I have to use these 3 tables as they are].

I hope this makes sense. 
Any ideas why this still does not work for me?

Comment: You say you haven't included the part referring to table2 - however, the error relates to that. Please update your example query to include it, along with some sample input data for all three tables. Maybe all you need is a distinct, but we can't tell at the moment.

Comment: @Boneist, my mistake there. I forgot to edit out that part. c refers to the select in table3. the alias is visible in the query.

Comment: Would a distinct id help if I have the count(*)=1 condition? As I was saying, IDs do not repeat, they are unique. So, if my thinking is correct, this should not be an issue.

Comment: Yes, but by the sounds of it, you have duplicate rows in table2. So, your final output might have two rows for the same address. That's not going to fly with your merge statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
MERGE INTO table1 a
                    USING (
                        SELECT max(ID), address
                          FROM table3 b 
                          WHERE address IS NOT NULL AND ID > 0 
                          GROUP BY address 
                          HAVING COUNT(*) = 1                
                    ) c 
                    ON (a.address = c.address)
                    WHEN MATCHED THEN
                        UPDATE SET a.ID = c.ID
                        WHERE a.ID = 0;
```

you have where condition in inner query but not in outer query. If you want your original query please try:

```
MERGE INTO table1 a
                    USING (
                        SELECT ID, address
                        FROM table3 b
                            AND address IN
                            (
                                SELECT address
                                FROM table3 
                                WHERE address IS NOT NULL
                                    AND ID> 0
                                GROUP BY address
                                HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
                            )
                           WHERE address IS NOT NULL
                                    AND ID> 0
                    ) c 
                    ON (a.address = c.address)
                    WHEN MATCHED THEN
                        UPDATE SET a.ID = c.ID
                        WHERE a.ID = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is more than likely due to the duplicate rows from table2. Here's a simple test case demonstrating the issue:

**Setup:**

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                 val VARCHAR2(1));

CREATE TABLE t2 (ID INTEGER,
                 val VARCHAR2(1));

INSERT INTO t1 (ID, val) VALUES (1, 'A');

INSERT INTO t2 (ID, val) VALUES (1, 'B');
INSERT INTO t2 (ID, val) VALUES (1, 'B');

COMMIT;
```

**Merge that will error:**

```
MERGE INTO t1 USING t2
  ON (t1.id = t2.id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET t1.val = t2.val;
```

> ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables

**Merge that will succeed:**

```
MERGE INTO t1 USING (SELECT DISTINCT id, val FROM t2) t2
  ON (t1.id = t2.id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET t1.val = t2.val;
```

N.B. The second merge will still fail if you have different values returned for val for the same id; that means you will have more than one row returned for a given id, and Oracle won't know which one to use to update the target table with.

In order to make sure your merge statement will work, you will need to ensure that you will return at most 1 row per address in the source subquery.

Comment: I always thought that it would update all my rows. Say I have an address 123 Willow St (which appears twice in the table I am trying to merge) with an id 5 in the table that contains ID. I expected it to put the id 5 to my address both times it sees this address. But thanks for clearing that up. However just putting `distinct ID` to my query does not solve my issue. Am I being thick and forgetting something?

Comment: You have to decide what you want to happen. Say you have your 123 Willow Street row in your target table (table1) and two rows with ids of 1 and 2 for the same address in your source query - what do you expect the id of the target table to end up as? 1 or 2? And what was the logic behind picking one? Once you have that, you should be able to replicate that logic in your source query - e.g. maybe you pick the lowest id, or maybe you pick the biggest, which means you're after a min/max query. Or, perhaps you're going about this in the wrong way; what is it you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I guess I have to go into more details that I thought. So here goes...`table3` let's say contains a list of all the addresses in a county and their corresponding ID. So here, you might have the same address twice with 2 distinct IDs ONLY if they are in different cities or areas. No city has the same address twice, right? The exact same address will not have 2 different IDs here. And if I have the same address twice, with 2 distinct IDs, I am excluding those cases with the count(*)=1.  The table I am merging into, `table1` will contain ids, addresses and some extra information.

Comment: For example, if I receive tax information for some addresses, I will want to store each address in this table, with the corresponding ID so I can link it to my main table, the one containing IDs. To be noted that `table3` is the source of IDs and all other tables just borrow IDs from there. And I am stressing the fact that those IDs are unique (there is a constraint on that) in `table3. For further exemplification, I in theory receive a bunch of tax data from 3 different sources. The party sending me that tax data does not know my ID (it is internally created) so there will be none.

Comment: Let's say that party sending the tax info sends me the same address (the exact same address) twice -- for any number of reasons. I am expecting when the merge is performed that each time the address is found in the merge, each row  will receive an ID (which will be the same). When the merge is performed I will have an ID with 2 appearances, but that is ok since it is the same address. `table1` does nothing but aggregate all my tax info --say nationwide. Am I thinking this wrong?  Did this make my issue any clearer?

Comment: It would be far clearer and easier if you could update your question with sample data for all three tables and the output that you're after.